# Cypress: regular expression inside jQuery selector ":contains()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, cypress

I want to use Cypress and a regular expression to select an element which contains a certain text.

This get() command works:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=tile]').contains(new RegExp(myVar))
```

But this command fails:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=tile]:contains(' + new RegExp(myVar) + ')')
```

Is there a way to use a regular expression within jQuery :contains()?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use `contains` one way you can use the regex is to just use `cy.contains(regex)` as mentioned in the [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Regular-Expression).

Suppose you have an Html element like:

```
<ul>
  <li>apples</li>
  <li>oranges</li>
  <li>bananas</li>
</ul>
```

So you cypress code to fetch `<li>bananas</li>` using only Regex will be:

```
cy.contains(/^b\w+/)
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this doesn't answer your question about jQuery, but maybe this would accomplish what you're after?

From [the Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Regular-Expression):

```
// yields <li>bananas</li>
cy.contains(/^b\w+/)
```